# How to tag people on iCloud Photos?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, photos.app

I discovered a few days ago that I can swipe up on a picture with my iPhone to associate all found faces with known contacts. This is an amazing feature and I wanted to do the same with other pictures that I have on my PC.

So I went to iCloud Photos created a new album and drop some vintage pictures of mine. I can then see this album on my iPhone. However, when I swipe up on this very album pictures I don't have the option to find faces.

I have an iPhone and an iPad and a PC. Would it be possible to sync my pictures across my Apple devices and tag faces and locations?

Answer (score 2):

To tag people on your IOS device you will require IOS 15. Go to a photo in Photos, drag up to see the metadata, if it has detected a face it will show the name or a "?" if it's a new person. Tag them and your good.

If you are on IOS 14 or earlier there is a workaroundto use the Photos.app in OSX and tag them there (info -> Add Faces), those seem to carry over to IOS eventually.

If the PC is running OSX, then photos are synced via iCloud photos to the Photos app. If it's running Windows, they you can download the "iCloud for Windows" app to have the photos synchronized.